# AspxGridView: Unable to sort without SortCount at the beginning

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using ASPxGridView with its default sorting property.

Before, it was not viewing any record after I press to any column name for sorting. But(there's a view all button) after I click to "View all", it was coming in a sorted way.
So I've figured out that I had to Bind grid again if (ASPxGridView1.SortCount == 1).

Now it's working, but only at the beginning, when I click to any column name for sorting, it returns no record, then it works perfectly.

So I need to do something instead of SortCount when the grid loads for the first time.
What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your code, but I think that the solution to this issue is discussed in the

[Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=K18183)